# How to require a private package hosted on bitbucket.org with composer?

Tags: git, version-control, composer-php, bitbucket

I'm trying to require a package I created from a private git repository on bitbucket.org.

I have the following `composer.json` in my private git repository:

```
{
    "name": "[user]/[package]",
    "type": "project",
    "license" : "proprietary",
    "authors": [],
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
```

If I call ...

```sh
composer require git@bitbucket.org:[user]/[package].git
```

... I get the following exception:

```
 [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint [user]/[package].git: Invalid version string "[user]/[package].git"
```

How can I install my private package?

## [UPDATE]

i have put the json file in my new project as suggested i am now getting this error.

```sh
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package [user]/[package] 1.0-dev exists as [user]/[package][1.0.x-dev, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Comment: You probably have the minium stability set to `stable` in your `composer.json`. Try to require `[user]/[package]: 1.0-dev@dev` or just `@dev` -> see this blog post about [stability flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell composer where to find your package(s) by adding repositories.

`composer` isn't able to require a package directly from a git repository like you tried.

Add your git repository containing the package under the `repositories` key as a `vcs` repository to the `composer.json` of the project you're intending to use the package in.

```
{
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://bitbucket.org/[user]/[package].git" }
  ],
  "require": {
    "[user]/[package]": "1.0-dev"
  }
}
```

You can also add the repository to your **global** `composer.json` to make it available for all projects.